# Trigger Build in Azure DevOps based on Subfolder commit

Tags: azure-devops

I have four folders in my Azure DevOps repo. I'm looking if I commit any change in folder A only that folder should trigger.
Is there any way to achieve this with single build definition.

Comment: Hi friend,  does the answer below resolved your question? If yes, appreciate for accepting it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a path filter in your trigger. For example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - A/*
```

This pipeline will be triggered only if you commit changes in folder A. Here is the document about [Path filters in CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) and you can find more detailed information there.